# Advice: Basement Floor

Tags: concrete, basement, paint

Somehow, we got away (for 12 years) with a carpeted basement and NO working drain tile. That all changed last year when we got 7 inches of rain, 3 of which covered our basement floor. Fast-forward: we now have new drain tile and sump pit/pump. We still don't want to go the "wall-to-wall" route, though, so here's what I have in front of me:

Remove ancient vinyl tile. Going to rent a tile stripper from Home Depot this weekend to get that done.

Polish concrete. Planning to fill cracks (for cosmetics), then rent a polisher from Home Depot.

Epoxy paint. Planning to buy a Rust-Oleum product and apply it myself.

I'm no Bob Vila, but I'm game to make the effort. My question for you all: what pitfalls am I walking blindly into? Any details I will regret not asking about?

Comment: How old are the tiles you're wanting to tear out?  Many old tiles had asbestos content in them, and although asbestos is perfectly safe when undisturbed, if you start breaking out the old tile pieces, there's a good chance asbestos particles will get in the air, if they're in the tiles themselves (or the adhesive that was used to put them down).

Comment: If you're going to be painting the floor, you wouldn't need to polish and fill cracks, except to get a smooth surface for the epoxy paint to adhere to, in which case it wouldn't need to look pretty, just smooth.

Comment: This is a broad, open-ended question, and is therefore off topic. Please see the [help] and revise to ask something more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Is the existing tile in good condition and solid to the floor (with minimal patching needed)?  If so, I might suggest leaving the tile intact, and putting a new surface on top, whether sheet linoleum, or linoleum planks that look really nice and are easy to apply.  This would be a lot less effort than tearing out the old tile, though might be more expensive in the end, depending on tile cost.